# Writing to stderr in golang - the simple way

Tags: go, stderr, stdio

I am looking to write to stderr; to write to stdout, this works:

```
fmt.Println(...)
```

Is there a better way to write to stderr than this:

```
 _, err := fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "This is an error message")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // Handle the error appropriately in your application
    }
```

seems weird that there is no simple API for this.

Comment: You can make a logger which prints to whatever you want, and the default happens to be stderr

Answer (score 3):

It is common for applications to ignore the error return from `fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, ...)`, just as it's common for applications ignore the error returned from `fmt.Println(...)`.

That is, it's common to write:

```
fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "This is an error message")
```

instead of the code in the question.

It is also common to use the [log package](https://godoc.org/log) to write to stderr (the standard logger writes to stderr by default).

If `os.Stderr` is a pipe and the pipe is closed, then calls to `fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, ...)` will cause the application to exit with signal SIGPIPE.